# Every time I need to clean and build my demandware project on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, demandware

Every time I modify my project, my changes(CSS & JS) do not reflect until I clean the project before the build.

also, it shows error on

```
<exec executable="/bin/bash" osfamily="unix" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="-c"/>
            <arg value="export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH; cd ${basedir}; gulp styles --basedir=${basedir}"/>
        </exec>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'Refresh using native hooks or polling option' so that you don't need to do the clean and build every time.

Go to Eclipse > Preferences > General > Workspace. Check the Refresh using native hooks option and apply these changes.